# field label class

Tags: theming, entities

How do I add a class to the label of every field of a specific content type.

- Module?
- Theme?
- Is this possible?

I'm using the bootstrap theme, if that makes any difference I can see that this theme is using form_element_label so I guess I need to override that for my specific node types.

Comment: Are you using D7 or D6 ?

Comment: Alternatively Have a look at this module for D7 http://drupal.org/project/In-Field-Labels and for D6 http://drupal.org/project/compact_forms

Comment: Drupal 7, neither of these really do what I need.

This functions does it twitter_bootstrap_field__page($variables)